# How BogoMips is calculated in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

How bogomips is calculated in linux kernel? What exactly is done to get this value?

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 *                Standalone BogoMips program
 *
 * Based on code Linux kernel code in init/main.c and
 * include/linux/delay.h
 *
 * For more information on interpreting the results, see the BogoMIPS
 * Mini-HOWTO document.
 *
 * version: 1.3 
 *  author: Jeff Tranter (Jeff_Tranter@Mitel.COM)
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef CLASSIC_BOGOMIPS
/* the original code from the Linux kernel */
static __inline__ void delay(int loops)
{
  __asm__(".align 2,0x90\n1:\tdecl %0\n\tjns 1b": :"a" (loops):"ax");
}
#endif

#ifdef QNX_BOGOMIPS
/* version for QNX C compiler */
void delay(int loops);
#pragma aux delay = \
     "l1:"       \
     "dec eax"   \
     "jns l1"    \
     parm nomemory [eax] modify exact nomemory [eax];
#endif

#ifdef PORTABLE_BOGOMIPS
/* portable version */
static void delay(int loops)
{
  long i;
  for (i = loops; i >= 0 ; i--)
    ;
}
#endif

int
main(void)
{
  unsigned long loops_per_sec = 1;
  unsigned long ticks;

  printf("Calibrating delay loop.. ");
  fflush(stdout);

  while ((loops_per_sec <<= 1)) {
    ticks = clock();
    delay(loops_per_sec);
    ticks = clock() - ticks;
    if (ticks >= CLOCKS_PER_SEC) {
      loops_per_sec = (loops_per_sec / ticks) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      printf("ok - %lu.%02lu BogoMips\n",
         loops_per_sec/500000,
         (loops_per_sec/5000) % 100
         );
      return 0;
    }
  }
  printf("failed\n");
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too bad that given these

> CFLAGS="-Wall -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -s -std=gnu99"

the standalone bogomips program always fails.  Changing from -O2 to -O0 makes it actually work, although reported values are much lower than reported by /proc/cpuinfo.  Interestingly, I have tried all the -f optimizer flags that are listed in the gcc (4.4.6) man page (for -O1, -O2 and even -O3), but the results don't change.  Upon adding -O1 it fails.  I'm wondering what is the strict set of optimizer flags that should be enabled/disabled for the delay loop to not get turned into a single scalar expression (causing the elapsed ticks to always remain 0).  Why does -O1 make it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't define any of the delay versions, just provided this prototype:

extern void delay(int loops);

and taking a cue from the QNX version, assembled the following with "nasm -felf64 delay.asm"

section .text
; prototype extern void delay(int loops);
global delay
delay:
dec edi     ;rdi is the first parameter passed in 64 bit C programs
jnz delay
ret

and finally

gcc -s -O2 -Wall bogomips.c delay.o -o bogomips

This is in 64 bit Linux. BTW, the result was **faster**  than the value in /proc/cpuinfo, and changing the -O(n) values in the gcc options hardly made a difference